Is there a Zapier Action to Retrieve Google Calendar Events?
I'm trying to integrate Zapier with Google Calendar to retrieve all events within a specific date range. While Zapier provides some Google Calendar actions, none of them seem to directly support fetching all events between two dates (from date to end date).
To achieve this, I attempted to create a custom Zapier action using a GET request based on the Google Calendar API documentation. I used the endpoint:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{{calendarID}}/events with timeMin and timeMax parameters for filtering events within the desired date range. Here is the Google Calendar API reference I followed: Google Calendar API - Events List.
However, when I execute the action, I receive the following error:
Error: Request to https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/testemail@gmail.com/events returned 500. Error during execution: Invalid URL.

Here's what I have tried:

Ensuring the calendar ID is correct.
Checking the URL syntax as per Google's documentation.
Verifying that timeMin and timeMax are correctly formatted (ISO 8601 date-time strings).

Despite these checks, the error persists.
Question:
Is there an existing Zapier action that can list all Google Calendar events within a specified date range that I might have overlooked? If not, what could be causing the "Invalid URL" error in my custom action, and how can I resolve it?
Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Can you ensure the calendar_id needed in the URL is an email address and not an alphanumeric id? IE. not testemail@gmail.com, but rather 123456789?

Thanks for your help @AdamDS, when I replaced the calendarID from an email address into a numerical one I start getting another error (400 bad request).

After further investigation, I've identified and resolved the problem.
The issue was related to the encoding of the calendar ID in the API request URL. In the URL, the calendar ID must be URL-encoded. For example, instead of using testemail@gmail.com directly in the URL, it should be encoded as testemail%40gmail.com. This change resolved the "Invalid URL" error I was encountering.
Here's a corrected example of the endpoint:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/testemail%40gmail.com/events

I hope this solution can help anyone else encountering a similar issue.
